# How to do multi pages web scraping to extract product data(product name, price) from Lazada by using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, analysis

I tried to extract product data of all the products (name and price) from a Lazada shop. However, There are total 102 pages but I only able to extract the first page of the data. Could anyone recognize the problem of my code?

url: https://www.lazada.com.my/guardian/?from=wangpu&langFlag=en&page=1&pageTypeId=2&q=All-Products

Below are my coding

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class ScrapeLazada():
    
    def scrape(self):
        url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/guardian/?from=wangpu&langFlag=en&page=1&pageTypeId=2&q=All-Products'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        
        products=[]
        for i in range(102):
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root")))
            time.sleep(2)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
            for item in soup.findAll('div', class_='Bm3ON'):
                product_name = item.find('div', class_='RfADt').text
                price = item.find('span', class_='ooOxS').text.replace('RM', '')
                products.append(
                    (product_name, price) 
                )

            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ant-pagination-next > button").click()
            time.sleep(3)

            df = pd.DataFrame(products, columns=['Product Name', 'Price'])
            print(df)

            df.to_excel('Lazada_Guardian_Scrape.xlsx', index=False)
            print('Data saved in local disk')
    
    
        driver.close()
        
sl = ScrapeLazada()
sl.scrape()
```

Below are my outcome. Apparently it just listed the first page products but have problem to list starting from the next page.

```
Product Name   Price
0   UPHAMOL 250 Children Suspension Delicious Oran...    7.80
1   Darlie Double Action Fresh + Clean Toothpaste ...   20.92
2                         Dermal Therapy Lip Balm 10g   12.78
3                Nurish No Teen Anti Acne Toner 100Ml   12.82
4                   Live-Well OCCUsharp 30s Pack-of-3  100.90
5                       Oxy Anti- Blackhead Wash 100g   11.95
6                Guardian Clear Assorted Plasters 20s    1.55
7          Selsun Blue 2 in 1 Treatment Shampoo 120ml   24.66
8                    Hansaplast Disney Frozen II 20's    8.90
9              Guardian Wet Wipes 10's Fragrance Free    3.46
10          Fruiser Shower Cream Pump Rosemilk 1000ml    8.10
11  Enchanteur Wonder Woman Handbag Edt Fighter Of...    9.90
12               Guardian Plastic Plasters 100s + 20s    9.10
13                          Sensodyne Fresh Mint 100g   12.50
14        Pantene Hair Fall Control Conditioner 165ML   10.89
15                Koolfever Cooling Gel For Babies 4s    8.60
16            Hada Labo Premium Whitening Essence 30g   85.90
17           Kinohimitsu J'pan Health Pad 10's + 10's   67.03
18           Ceradan Moisturising Hand Sanitiser 50ml   26.74
19                   Sunsweet Pitted Prune 340g (USA)   23.20
20                      **21st Century Probiotics 30s   17.00
21  Kundal Honey and Macadamia Hair Treatment Pear...   27.22
22      Sunsilk Super Conditioner Damage Rescue 180ml   11.28
23                    LACTOGG probiotic capsules 30's  125.10
24                              Rosken Bio Serum 50ml   28.82
25           Simple Kind To Skin Soothing Toner 200ml   21.34
26                  L’Oreal White Perfect Toner 200ml   30.25
27                            Total Image S Tummy 60s   63.00
28        Durex Invisible Extra Lubricant Condom 10's   51.13
29          3 Legs Tolnaftate Cream Pack Of 2 (2X10g)   14.66
30          Hansaplast Universal Water Resistant 20's    4.20
31     Perfume Generics Perfume Oil Paris Hilton 10Ml    8.90
32                Aiken Shampoo - Intense Repair 350G   12.68
33                            GoodMorning VGrains 1kg   62.52
34                        Woodwards Gripe Water 148ml   14.00
35          Difflam Hextra Sore Throat Lozenges 2.4mg    8.00
36                               Okamoto 003 Cool 3's   14.50
37                 Dettol Hand Sanitizer Refresh 50ml    6.25
38  Avene Pre-Serum Hydrating Essence-In-Lotion 200Ml   87.30
39  Guardian Essential Lavender Refreshing Body Wa...   10.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lazada_Guardian.py", line 43, in <module>
    sl.scrape()
  File "Lazada_Guardian.py", line 30, in scrape
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ant-pagination-next > button").click()
  File "/Users/chingkarlok/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/chingkarlok/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/chingkarlok/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/chingkarlok/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="ant-pagination-item-link" type="button" tabindex="-1">...</button> is not clickable at point (1186, 693). Other element would receive the click: <html lang="en" class=" ">...</html>
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.137)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010295d670 chromedriver + 4298352
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102955bbc chromedriver + 4266940
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102588758 chromedriver + 280408
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001025cb444 chromedriver + 554052
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001025c8e84 chromedriver + 544388
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001025c663c chromedriver + 534076
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001025c5530 chromedriver + 529712
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001025b8428 chromedriver + 476200
8   chromedriver                        0x00000001025b7b90 chromedriver + 474000
9   chromedriver                        0x00000001025fc080 chromedriver + 753792
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001025b62d0 chromedriver + 467664
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001025b7354 chromedriver + 471892
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010291d6c4 chromedriver + 4036292
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102921c64 chromedriver + 4054116
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001029282d8 chromedriver + 4080344
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000102922970 chromedriver + 4057456
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001028f98dc chromedriver + 3889372
17  chromedriver                        0x000000010294125c chromedriver + 4182620
18  chromedriver                        0x00000001029413b4 chromedriver + 4182964
19  chromedriver                        0x00000001029500f4 chromedriver + 4243700
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a0e2e06c _pthread_start + 148
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a0e28e2c thread_start + 8
```

Comment: What is error you are getting. Paste the stack trace in the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reminding. Updated the error that I got in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can solve this issue in two ways.

1. Using Action chains to click on the next button.

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
products_list = []
for i in range(102):
    nextbutton = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".ant-pagination-next > button")))
    actions.move_to_element(nextbutton).click().perform()
    time.sleep(2)
```

2. Using `page` value in the URL and iterate over and no need to perform click action on next button.

```
for i in range(1,102):
    driver.get(f"https://www.lazada.com.my/guardian/?from=wangpu&langFlag=en&page={i}&pageTypeId=2&q=All-Products")
    ...
```

But for scraping can use Request library from Python. Refer [Web scraping with API](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api/) to find API and extract data.

```
import requests
import json

for i in range(1,5):
    url = f"https://www.lazada.com.my/guardian/?ajax=true&from=wangpu&isFirstRequest=true&langFlag=en&page={i}&pageTypeId=2&q=All-Products"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()["mods"]["listItems"]
    for j in range(len(data)):
        name = data[j]["name"]
        price = data[j]["priceShow"]
        print(f"{name} : {price}")

Output:
PHAMOL 250 Children Suspension Delicious Orange Flavour 60ml : RM7.80
Darlie Double Action Fresh + Clean Toothpaste Original Strong Mint 225g x 2 (Value Pack) : RM20.92
Dermal Therapy Lip Balm 10g : RM12.78
Nurish No Teen Anti Acne Toner 100Ml : RM12.82
Live-Well OCCUsharp 30s Pack-of-3 : RM100.90
...
```

Comment: I only tried the solution 2 and it worked perfectly. Can't believe it just 1 sentence of code away to complete  the mission. You are amazing @pmadhu. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also appreciate the Web scraping with API solution. It seems way easier to do web scraping. Is the solution worked for Shopee as well?

Comment: Haven't tried for Shopee yet.

Comment: Alright. Anyway, you are so great. I have one more question, I actually got an excel list of products (240 items) and I required to price comparison with another Lazada shop, and this is why I extract the product data. 

However, I have no idea how to only choose the 240 products I want in the shop so instead I just extract all data of products from the shop first then only think about next steps to filter out the products I do not need. 

Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Comment: Have no idea on what basis you are trying to filter. Since you have already got the data need to iterate over and remove the unwanted entries or create a new list and add all those entries which matches the criteria to filter out.

Comment: noted. Thank you so much. May I know not all page in Lazada can be web scraping with API right? As I want to try to scrape the product data in single product page(Let's say I click the first product of above all-product page) but seems no API found.